# How to get a new paragraph indented?

Tags: paragraphs, templates

I am trying to define a tab at the beginning of a sentence. If I use `\tab` the effect is that a new line is inserted and the text is aligned to left. 
The same effect if I use `\par`. I am using a template that defines the following stylesheet:

```
\documentclass{thesis.cs.pub.ro} 
\makeindex
\usepackage{epigraph,csquotes,natbib}        % required for bibliography
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} 
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5} 
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82} 
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}   
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2 }   
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\input{src/global}
\begin{frontmatter} % roman numbering

%\maketitle %\input{template/titlepage.ro} \input{template/titlepage.en}

\begin{acknowledgements} \input{src/base/acknowledgements} \end{acknowledgements}

\begin{abstract} \input{src/base/abstract} \end{abstract}

\input{template/contents.pages}

\printabbrev

\end{frontmatter} % end roman numbering

% 1.5 linespacing for the contents  \onehalfspacing

\input{src/main}

%\appendix %\input{src/appendix/index}

\bibliography{src/main} \bibliographystyle{plain}

%\printindex

\end{document}
```

I assume that there is some setting in the above template that makes the tab to not work properly. Any idea what is wrong? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please specify what your problem is. Is it with `listings`?

Comment: The problem is that i can not write paragraphs of text. The text is left aligned whatever I do. I want to have a tab inserted at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable? Remember that we don't have access to your additional files.

Comment: Do you want to indent every sentence or every paragraph?

Comment: I want to indent every paragraph.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. I believe most of the code you provide is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to do this manually, latex automatically indents every paragraph -- except that the class you are using explicitly set the width of this indent to zero.

But this can easily be changed. Everything you have to do is to adjust the `\parindent`, which specifies how far the first line of the paragraphs is indented.

```
\documentclass{thesis.cs.pub.ro}

\setlength{\parindent}{4em}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, non- ummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is working but there is still a problem. When I define a new paragraph inserting an empty line in the code the effect is that a new line is inserted in the result, too. Any idea on how to mark the beginning of the new paragraph?

Comment: @Sorin Your questions would be much easier to answer, if you would make a MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem.

Comment: @Sorin Try also `\setlength{\parskip}{0em}`. But this is really a shot in the dark. Personally, i would bin that template. Reconsider if you really need to use it. If yes, ask yourself why the developer of the template ecided for a paragraph skip instead of indentation.